# Extracting data from OSM with ogr2ogr --- blank output

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, ogr2ogr

I have an issue while extracting data from osm via ogr2ogr.

**What I tried:**

When I run from command line:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" example.shp source.pbf -lco ENCODING=UTF-8 -progress -sql "SELECT name, tourism from points where tourism is not null"
```

I am getting shapefile with all tourism tags, but I wanted to select only specific tags to avoid doing selection afterwards.

So I run (**I added zoo and museum to OSMCONFIG.ini**):

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" example.shp source.pbf -lco ENCODING=UTF-8 -progress -sql "SELECT name, tourism from points where tourism in (zoo, museum)"
```

and my output is blank, In the shapefile I will get name and tourism collumns, but they are empty.

**Question:**

How one can select tags that one only need?

Comment: At least you could try to correct your SQL. If OGR SQL is doing the standard SQL stuff it now tries to find cases where value of field tourism equals the value of field zoo or field museum. So have a try with `where tourism in ('zoo', 'museum')`.

Comment: Thank you......